Using Github Actions from another private repository fails in the second step
I have 2 repos. One has API code and other has infra code. The infra code also has some GH actions which I want to re-use.
I have created a Personal token which I am using to access the repo. I have also provided access.
These are from Settings > Actions > General
Allow all actions and reusable workflows
Accessible from repositories owned by the user 'org'
Here is the Workflow in the API
name: Deploy to AWS ECS
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Checkout Infra Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: myapp/myapp-infra
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          path: myapp-infra 
          ref: main 

      - name: List Infra Actions1
        run: ls -la myapp-infra/.github/actions/ #This lists all actions

      - name: Show Current Directory
        run: pwd # /home/runner/work/myapp-api/myapp-api

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: ./myapp-infra/.github/actions/setup-node #runs fine

      - name: Show Current Directory
        run: pwd # /home/runner/work/myapp-api/myapp-api

      - name: List Infra Actions2
        run: ls -la myapp-infra/.github/actions/ # fails

      - name: Install NPM Dependencies
        uses: ./myapp-infra/.github/actions/npm-install #fails

The action setup-node runs fine and npm-install fails.
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/myapp-api/myapp-api/myapp-infra/.github/actions/npm-install'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?

The infra repo file structure.

Any help is appreciated. Can provide more info if required.
From my initial investigation I have found out that the myapp-infra which is created by checkout is getting removed after any action from that repo is run. I initially thought that a specific action is the culprit but I have ruled that out as after the execution of any action, the repo folder is missing. The directory before and after the execution remains the same though.
So the million dollar questions are:

Should we checkout after each actions?
Can we checkout to a specific path so that they won't be removed?
Is there any other way than checkout? (both the repos are private under the same organisation.)

Here are some logs from GH actions.
Download action repository 'actions/setup-node@v4' (SHA:60edb5dd545a775178f52524783378180af0d1f8)
Run ./myapp-infra/.github/actions/setup-node
Run actions/checkout@v4
Syncing repository: myapp/myapp-api
Getting Git version info
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/3790bc2a-42db-4f29-81ac-acaafa9303b0' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/myapp-api/myapp-api
/usr/bin/git config --local --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/myapp/myapp-api
Removing previously created refs, to avoid conflicts
/usr/bin/git submodule status
Cleaning the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
/usr/bin/git sparse-checkout disable
/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all extensions.worktreeConfig
Checking out the ref
/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'e95d322d898d11920cdeb2e384cb323f567deac7'
Run NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)
Run actions/setup-node@v4
Found in cache @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.12.2/x64
Environment details
  node: v20.12.2
  npm: 10.5.0
  yarn: 1.22.22
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/myapp-api/myapp-api/myapp-infra/.github/actions/npm-install'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?


The error seems pretty clear. Could you share the git repositories so that we can check their folders / files structure and help you troubleshooting?

Unfortunately I can't as it is a private repo. However I have provide a screenshot of the directory structure.

Ok, could you try configuring a working directory in the step returning errors?

Didn't help. The root cause that I have understood from this is that there is no issues with any steps as I reversed the order and it works fine. After any step from the infra repo is complete, the infra repo is getting removed. ls -la myapp-infra/.github/actions/ works before the actions and fails after the action.So do I have to checkout every time?

It shouldn't be necessary to call the checkout action many times. Did you investigate what is removing the infra repo after the action execution?

Thanks for that. I couldn't find any steps/action/log that says that this has been removed. I have added some more logs in the question above.

It seems that your ./myapp-infra/.github/actions/setup-node local action is using the actions/checkout internally (ref: Run actions/checkout@v4 and Syncing repository: myapp/myapp-api). It's probably overwriting the myapp/myapp-infra folder your previously set there in your workflow. Could you check the setup-node action setup you are running?

Thanks a lot mate. That was the issue. This is now solved. Champion.

Great, I'll add an official answer then :D

As shared in the workflow logs you added to the question, your ./myapp-infra/.github/actions/setup-node local action is using the actions/checkout internally.

Run actions/checkout@v4
Syncing repository: myapp/myapp-api

This action will overwrite the myapp/myapp-infra folder previously set in the workflow using the actions/checkout@v4.
In that case, you'll need to adapt your workflow or your local action to match your expected behavior.
I suggest you to remove this actions/checkout usage from your setup-node local action, as you don't seem to need it in your context.
